# Ubuntu on Windows 10 - SSH “Permissions xxxx for private key are too open

Tags: windows-10, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a key file located at `C:\private-key.pem` and I have a soft link to it on the Ubuntu subsystem: `~/.ssh/private-key.pem  ->  /mnt/c/private-key.pem`.

When I'm trying to ssh into some remote machine from the Ubuntu subsystem, I get:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0777 for '/home/artur/.ssh/private-key.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "/home/artur/.ssh/private-key.pem": bad permissions
Permission denied (publickey).
```

- This began after the 1803 update for Windows:  I was trying to use `chmod 400` for the key on `C:\` and within `~/.ssh` on WSL.  I  trying to set owner to me and remove all other users' ACLs on Windows for this key file, but every time I get `Permission denied` or 
   `Permissions XXXX for '/home/artur/.ssh/private-key.pem' are too open`.

Can anybody help me and explain how keys permissions should be configured on Windows and the Ubuntu subsystem?

Comment: I also tried chmod 400 for key on subsystem and set owner just to me from windows security. But the issue still remains same. someone please help. This happened to me with the recent windows 10 update.

Comment: Is this your issue https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3181?

Comment: For me what worked is setting `options = "metadata"` under the automount section in /etc/wsl.conf then running `chmod 600` on the ssh file (check https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/automatically-configuring-wsl/). You also need to log out and log back in and make sure that `C:` now has the automount option in `mount -l`

More info about the automount options could be found here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/chmod-chown-wsl-improvements/

Comment: This answer may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75001941/12326605

Answer (score 47):

Solution that works for me in windows WSL (without changing file mode):

```
sudo ssh -i keyfile <user>@ip
```

Comment: I don’t understand.  Can you explain what you mean?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: If WSL still shows access permissions for group and others, this is not an acceptable solution. SSH keys must only be accessible to the user they're intended for and no other user or group. Allowing for anything other the 600/400 permissions defeats the purpose of utilizing an SSH key, as it compromises the security of said key.

Comment: I have no clue how this works, but, this solution works. It may not be the ideal solution(using sudo to ssh, -_-), but, it worked. Some update had messed it up for few months already! Hope it gets fixed.

Comment: I found the right answer here - https://superuser.com/a/1323647/352182
You cannot modify a file inside of /mnt (windows file system), copy the file to your linux and then it works as expected.

Comment: I agree with @JW0914, doing this compromises the security of the key. JW0914's answer should be the accepted answer.

Comment: For those who don’t get it: _he told you to `sudo` it._

Comment: @КонстантинВан `sudo` should _never_ be utilized with `ssh`.  The reason why issuing with `sudo` works is because it's now likely being executed as `root`, and this is _not_ the correct way to do this and _is_ a massive security risk, as _Allowing for anything other the 600/400 permissions defeats the purpose of utilizing an SSH key, compromising the security of the key._

Comment: Thx, I got the same error when using rsync with wsl and could it solve like this: `wsl rsync -Pav -e "sudo ssh -i /mnt/c/Users/myname/.ssh/keyfile" /mnt/c/Users user@host:/backup/win-user`.

Answer (score 26):

I'm reading between the lines, and assuming you're using a Linux subsystem in Windows 10. When you symlinked the Windows file from `C:\` into the Linux file system in `$HOME/.ssh`, the permissions of the actual file are still under control of Windows, and the permissions shown to you in the Linux window just best represent the Windows permissions; you can't change the permissions on the Windows files in `/mnt/c` from Linux. [This FAQ from Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq#are-files-in-the-linux-drive-different-from-the-mounted-windows-drive) talks about how files are handled in the two overlapping file systems.

The file you need to change the permission on is the file the symlink is pointing so, so that means the file in `/mnt/c`

It doesn't seem possible to give user-only access to a Windows file. Even if you disable permission inheritance on a file and give only your own user read permission, the Linux permissions still show as `-r--r--r--`, so that won't be usable for `~/.ssh`

The only option appears to be copying the file from Windows into Linux, at which point you can use `chmod` and `chown` on it.

Answer (score 16):

Copy the SSH key over to your WSL `~/.ssh` directory, as an SSH key with anything other than 600/400 permissions compromises the key.

- *Once the key is copied over, ensure it's EOLs have been changed to LF.*

  - There's a number of ways to do so, from the [Atom text editor](https://atom.io) to CLI solutions like `dos2unix`, `unix2dos`, etc.
- See @simpleuser's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1322665/529800) below to understand why permissions cannot be changed via Windows, of which necessitates copying the key to the WSL's `~/.ssh` directory

Answer (score 7):

The Windows 10 permissions vs WSL permissions problem is only a problem if the .pem file is in the Windows file system accessible under a mount point, e.g. somewhere in /mnt/c .

If you move the file to under your WSL home directory, e.g. directory /home/.ssh, then you can do a `chmod 400 yourkeyfile.pem` on the file.

The way WSL works, the standard Linux root directories like bin, etc, home, usr are not visible to Windows 10, hence you can do a `chmod` on any file just as you were working on a real Linux system.

Comment: I copied it instead of moving it, so both OSs can use it.

Answer (score 3):

I am using Linux Windows Shell on Windows 10 Pro and  also installed cygwin

Matching WSL UID to cygwin UID solved the problem.
Find the cygwin UID in the cygwin terminal via `id`

Two steps to match the UID:

1. Open `cmd.exe` with administrator privileges and edit, with the new UID, via  `regedit`.

   ```
   HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss{cefb...cb50}\DefaultUid
   ```
2. Change the UID in WSL by using, in the WSL terminal:

   ```bash
   sudo vi /etc/passwd
   chmod 600 ~/.ssh/private-key.pem
   ```

Reference:

- [WSL: How to Change the UID?](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3576)
- [How to Reset Kali Linux Password in Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/1330054/how-to-reset-kali-linux-password-in-windows-subsystem-for-linux)

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, delete all others permissions:

1. ```bsh
    chmod 400 'keyname.pem'
   ```
2. Right-click `keyname.pem` → *Setting* → *Security*  → Delete all users/groups except you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using WSL, you can copy file.pem to `~/.ssh/`

Copy file .pem

```shell
cp file.pem ~/.ssh/
```

Change permissions:

```shell
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/file.pem
```

Done, try again with your `ssh-add`

```shell
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/file.pem
```

Comment: This was the solution I was looking for... chmod 600.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1325482/915621) above, I am using Linux Windows Shell on Windows 10 Pro, and the v1803 update broke SSH in the shell.

- There is no equivalent to `chmod 600` within Windows, but you can leave your `.pem` unchanged with file permission `777`, running the following, which will log straight in *(not sure why)*:

  ```bsh
  sudo ssh -i  'my777Keyfile.pem'  ubuntu@12.34.45.78
  ```

Comment: Did you test your answer?   I used the GUI in Windows to change the icacl but after some experimentation I couldn't match the Linux SSH requirement that it's restricted down to the ssh user.  From memory I always needed to be in at least one group.  This meant that I could restrict to (500 or 540 I think) but that still won't work.  If I get chance I'll experiment with your method of moving the key to the .shh directory in WSL as that would be a simple and effective solution.

Comment: Since you implied the first two steps in my answer didn't work for you, I've removed them, leaving the last, and only, solution, as SSH keys _should never_ be readable or accessible to any but the user they're intended for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really simple WSL solution, normally not requiring `sudo`:

```bsh
cat 'mykey.pem' > 'wslkey.pem'
chmod 400 wslkey.pem
ssh -i 'wslkey.pem' ec2-user@[PUBLIC-IP-OF-YOUR-INSTANCE]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use named pipes:

```
key="/tmp/ssh-$(openssl rand -hex 16)"
mkfifo "${key}"
chmod 600 "${key}"
cat my_key_file_with_bogus_permissions > "${key}" &
ssh-add "${key}"
rm -f "${key}"
```