# Unable to change file permissions on Ubuntu Bash for Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, bash, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was trying to use an ssh instance and I received the following error, which is odd since I tried to change the permission using `chmod`, but that didn't seem to work as permissions were still `777`:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0777 for 'privkey.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "privkey.pem": bad permissions
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I opened `git bash` and was able to SSH into my instance with no problem, and permissions were not `777` as well.

Comment: So **which update**? What happens if you roll it back?

Comment: Similar to this https://superuser.com/q/1321072/726810

Comment: For everyone not able to get the wsl.conf options working, you have to restart the LxssManager service. Closing the WSL instances is not good enough sometimes.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

If you're referencing files in the Windows file system, they do not, by default, retain Linux permissions.
However, there's a way to enable that. Edit or create (using `sudo`) `/etc/wsl.conf` and add the following:

```
[automount]
options = "metadata"
```

Shut down all WSL instances and restart an instance, and any `chmod` changes are now retained.

Comment: Does not work for me. I did exactly as you suggest, but permission set using `chmod` still do not reflect when doing a `ls -al`. Strangely enough (and this was also the case prior to doing this change), certain `chmod` values work while others don't. For e.g, 0600 has no effect but 0400 changes it to -r-xr-xr-x.

Comment: @Ash make sure your WSL permissions doesn't contradict the Windows permission. E.g. if you mark a file read-only in Windows, it won't be writable in WSL either, as the Windows permissions overrules the WSL permissions.

Comment: @nilskp The file is not marked Readonly under Windows and the Windows permissions for it are Full Control for SYSTEM, Administrators, and the user. If Windows permissions overrule, then by that very statement, doesn't it mean that any `chmod` done via WSL won't be observed?

Comment: @Ash, take a look at the `options` in Basil A's answer. It's possible you need one or both of those masks. I don't know enough about the issue to resolve this.

Comment: @nilskp Please take a look at my comment to Basil A's answer, which I posted at the same time as my original comment to this answer. In short, neither approach (yours or Basil A's) works for me. Possibly because the file in question for me in under `/mnt` ; probably why erobertc's answer worked for me.

Comment: I had to restart my machine after the changes.

Comment: Note: You must **restart** the service -- **not just exit** the terminal. \
Use `wsl.exe --shutdown` & `wsl.exe`. See https://superuser.com/a/1347725/997622

Answer (score 31):

The correct way to handle this:

1. Create `/etc/wsl.conf` with the following:

   ```
   [automount]
   enabled  = true
   root     = /mnt/
   options  = "metadata,umask=22,fmask=11"
   ```

   To understand the meaning of each parameter above, please refer to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/02/07/automatically-configuring-wsl/) article on MSDN
2. Close all WSL terminals and open a new one
3. Restart your machine (as indicated by some comments)

Now you are all set; changing permissions of a file in Windows from `/mnt/c/` will be reflected, and mounted, correctly within WSL on startup via the `metadata` option.

Comment: Does not work for me. I did exactly as you suggest, but permission set using `chmod` still do not reflect when doing a `ls -al`. Strangely enough (and this was also the case prior to doing this change), certain `chmod` values work while others don't. For e.g, 0600 has no effect but 0400 changes it to -r-xr-xr-x.

Comment: fmask must be set to 111. See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/chmod-chown-wsl-improvements/

Comment: This answer works well for me. @ArunprasadRajkumar, fmask should *not* be 111 - using this removes the executable flag from all files by default (which is noted in the article that you link to) and is probably not what you want. Using `fmask=11` uses executable flags from the file system by default so works well.

Comment: To clarify my previous comment, `fmask=111` removes execution rights from all files for owner, group, and anonymous users. `fmask=11` removes execution rights for group and anonymous users only, while using the execution right from the file system for owner (this is probably what you want, and works well with git). `umask=22` removes write rights from files and directories for group and anonymous users.

Comment: This worked for me ONLY after I restarted my machine.

Comment: This is likely because WSL seems to persist a little while after exiting it's shell.

Answer (score 26):

Is the private key on your Windows filesystem (under /mnt/)? You can't modify the permissions of files on Windows's filesystem using chmod on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows. You'll have to copy the private key to your WSL home directory (~) and do it there.

Some discussion here: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/81

Comment: There are at least 3 pages to that discussion.  You really should quote the information you feel is relevant to the author.

Comment: @iii So what changed recently? Did you install any windows updates? Did you change any config files? Please edit and update your question.

Comment: @iii - Which update?  Your question makes no reference to the fact it was working previously.  Your question also makes no reference that you recently installed an update.  I disagree with this answer, because the link is from before WSL was modified (I believe), to support what you are trying to do.  Which is the reason I was pressing the author to elaborate thier answer

Comment: @Ramhound, the relevant information from that discussion is paraphrased in my answer, I just added that link as a reference source. The relevant information is in the first reply there.

I didn't know that the questioner only encountered this problem after a Windows update, but they haven't said whether the key is on the Windows filesystem, so I still think that's the most likely explanation until they indicate otherwise.

Comment: Not sure why people are getting upset about this answer even though it presents the truth (if you think otherwise about the `/mnt` restriction, point to the relevant documentation in your comment). I encountered the exact same behaviour; permissions for files under the `/mnt` directory could not be changed using `chmod`. So I had to move my ssh keys to my `/home/<user>` directory, and then `chmod` worked as expected.

Comment: changing the file location to Linux file system folders worked for me.

Comment: This is a weird one - for some reason my path was moved from /c/Users/username to /mnt/c/Users/username after a reboot.  I'm still not sure how that could have happened on it's own.  I didn't have any issues until I tried to chmod and now it does nothing.

Comment: Thanks @erobertc . This worked for me. And also made me aware of the difference in WSL between mounted folders and normal linux folders.

Comment: @Ash: I'm facing the same problem, but for me I can't change the file permissions in a folder that is in my Linux home directory itself. It's in my ~/.aws directory. Again, just like you changing it to 400 works but changing to 600 doesn't (actually changing it to 600 effectively changes it to 777 I think). Any other ideas?

Answer (score 10):

I created an alias that gets loaded in my `~/.bashrc` file and allows to unmount/remount the `C:/` drive in the `/mnt/c/` folder with `"metadata" permissions.

```
alias win-chmod="cd ~ && sudo umount /mnt/c && sudo mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/c -o metadata && cd -"
```

This allows me to only enable `chmod` when I need it, preventing unwanted changes to the mounted file system. It's just a matter of invoking

```bsh
$ ls -l | grep myfile
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root          0 Dec 12 16:34 myfile.txt
$ win-chmod
/mnt/c/Users/myself/Documents/myfolder
$ chmod 666 myfile.txt
$ ls -l | grep myfile
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root          0 Dec 12 16:34 myfile.txt
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the only thing that worked for me after hours of research

Comment: +1 for ingenuity.  But the above solution by @Basil also worked, after rebooting (required)

Comment: worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add to @basilA's answer, because it's not that easy to create a `/etc/wsl.conf` file, especially since I kept getting:

```
-bash: /etc/conf.wsl: Permission denied
```

even if I ran commands with `sudo`. Anyway, the trick is to change to the root user.

So, from a regular command prompt, type the following commands:

- `wsl`
- `sudo su`
- ```
  cat > /etc/wsl.conf << EOF
  [automount]
  options = "metadata"
  EOF
  ```

Comment: The `sudo su` bit was what was missing from all the explanations I'd seen.

Answer (score 3):

Copy the key file to anywhere in the Linux Sub system then change the permission and  connect.

`cp /mnt/path/to/key/file /home/$USER/`

`chmod 400 /home/$USER/key_file_name.pem`

Comment: nothing above worked for me; thanks for this!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue that my files were stored on an external hard drive which happend to be formated in exFAT.
Well you cannot change permissions for files on any FAT
and if you try it may end in weird results.
So you have to copy your files to a hard drive formated in NTFS and try again.
(btw: there is also no security tab in the file properties on FAT)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

NONE of those answers worked for me
but

1. opening a **Windows PowerShell Terminal** with **Administration rights** and then
2. opening an Ubuntu tab and
3. executing `chmod 666 /path/to/the/file/I/want` (feel free to change permissions number)

did the trick

[image: how to open the terminal with admin rights]
(1. right-click, 2. right-click, 3. left-click)

good luck with this annoying issue, hope this will fix it

Answer (score -1):

You cannot give 777 permission to *.pem file

Use `chmod 400 filename.pem`

it will fixed the issue

in some system you can use  `chmod 600 filename.pem`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: When i face the same situation i just copy the pem  file in window linux subsystem  and run this command it  resolved my issue