# WSL (Ubuntu 20.04) - unstable permissions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rsync, file-permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm new to WSL and trying to use `rsync` for snapshot backups. Everything seems to be working as intended... except that `rsync` refuses to copy some files, citing a permission error with `send_files`.

So I tried to change globally the permissions for all files and folders, to make them all readable. Again, failure with certain files. I then went to look at these specific directories and found this, for example:

```
m17awl@M17A:/mnt/d/My Documents/software projects/operative/LuceneIndexer_3/3.0.12/lib$ ls -lsa
total 48332
   0 drwxrwxrwx 1 m17awl m17awl     512 Jan 21  2020 .
   0 drwxrwxrwx 1 m17awl m17awl     512 Jan 21  2020 ..
  52 ---------- 1 m17awl m17awl   51141 Jan 23  2020 LuceneIndexer_3-3.0.12.jar
   4 ---------- 1 m17awl m17awl    3482 Jan 23  2020 animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar
2020 ---------- 1 m17awl m17awl 2067867 Jan 23  2020 ant-1.9.13.jar
```

hmmm... no permissions. OK, I try to change these, seemingly successfully:

```
m17awl@M17A:/mnt/d/My Documents/software projects/operative/LuceneIndexer_3/3.0.12/lib$ sudo chmod -R +r .
[sudo] password for m17awl:
m17awl@M17A:/mnt/d/My Documents/software projects/operative/LuceneIndexer_3/3.0.12/lib$ ls -lsa
total 48332
   0 drwxrwxrwx 1 m17awl m17awl     512 Jan 21  2020 .
   0 drwxrwxrwx 1 m17awl m17awl     512 Jan 21  2020 ..
  52 -r-xr-xr-x 1 m17awl m17awl   51141 Jan 23  2020 LuceneIndexer_3-3.0.12.jar
   4 -r-xr-xr-x 1 m17awl m17awl    3482 Jan 23  2020 animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar
2020 -r-xr-xr-x 1 m17awl m17awl 2067867 Jan 23  2020 ant-1.9.13.jar
```

I run `rsync` again... and get the same permission failures, including with these files in this particular directory:

```
m17awl@M17A:/mnt/d/My Documents$ rsync --progress --update --recursive --times --link-dest=/mnt/f/Backups/rsync/My\ Documents/snapshot2021-02-21T203900/ /mnt/d/My\ Documents/ /mnt/f/Backups/rsync/My\ Documents/snapshot2021-02-22T071700/
sending incremental file list
...
rsync: send_files failed to open "/mnt/d/My Documents/software projects/operative/LuceneIndexer_3/3.0.12/bin/LuceneIndexer_3": Permission denied (13)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/mnt/d/My Documents/software projects/operative/LuceneIndexer_3/3.0.12/lib/LuceneIndexer_3-3.0.12.jar": Permission denied (13)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/mnt/d/My Documents/software projects/operative/LuceneIndexer_3/3.0.12/lib/animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar": Permission denied (13)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/mnt/d/My Documents/software projects/operative/LuceneIndexer_3/3.0.12/lib/ant-1.9.13.jar": Permission denied (13)
```

... and when I go back and look at the directory again I find the permissions on these files have been "destroyed" (i.e. again set to `----------`).

Anyone got any idea what's going here... any solutions?

Incidentally, the source medium, where the problem seems to be happening, is an internal SSD, 250 GB, formatted NTFS. The destination medium (/mnt/f) is an external hard drive, spinning plates type, 750 GB, formatted NTFS.

Comment: Does this help? [Unable to change file permissions on Ubuntu Bash for Windows 10](https://superuser.com/q/1323645/432690)

Comment: Thanks, very useful. So far, just creating the file /etc/wsl.conf with that line, and then restarting wsl.exe, has NOT worked. But there are other answers there, suggestions that other things have to be added to that file, suggestions that you have to reboot, etc. Hopefully something will work as I plod through those answers!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Kamil Maciorowski's comment and link I did some experiments, which appear to have led to success:

1 - as per [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1392722/419196), create (or modify if exists) a file /etc/wsl.conf:

```
[automount]
enabled  = true
root     = /mnt/
options  = "metadata,umask=22,fmask=11"
```

2 - reboot machine

3 - set your permissions as required, in my case read permissions for the source location

4 - rsync

NB some other answers with the above linked answer suggest that no /mnt/... locations (i.e. Windows 10 partitions) under WSL can be trusted to keep their permissions. SO FAR, in my case, this seems to be false. As mentioned, my source location is an internal SSD drive formatted NTFS, and it appears so far to be working OK.

Comment: I'd also recommend `uid=1000,gid=1000` in your options for rsync.  See [this github issue/comment](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3187#issuecomment-388904048).  The `metadata` will work for files created under WSL, but the `uid/gid` are needed for files created under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

While it's good to hear that you resolved the issue for this use case, I'd still recommend a slightly different solution.

In your `/etc/wsl.conf`, add the following:

```
[automount]
options  = "metadata,umask=22,fmask=11,uid=1000,gid=1000"
```

Of course, set the `uid` and `gid` to your user.  Technically, the `metadata`, `fmask`, and `umask` options aren't even necessary with the `uid/gid` set.  At least not for the `rsync` use-case.  They are still nice-to-have in place, though.

See [this Github issue/comment](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3187#issuecomment-388904048) for more details.  Summary is that "metadata" will allow WSL to store permissions for files created *by WSL* on the drvfs drive, but files created *by Windows* would still be assigned to root.  As a result, if `rsync` includes these files, there would still be permissions issues.  `uid/gid`, on the other hand, will assign WSL ownership of files to your user regardless of whether they are created in WSL or Windows.

The `enabled` and `root` options from your answer are already set to those values by default by WSL, so they really shouldn't be necessary at all.

Comment: Thanks. I am not a Linux expert so a lot of this is over my head. My uid and gid both seem, indeed, to be 1000. All the files I'm dealing with here are Windows-created, obviously I've had to set their permissions using sudo. But in fact they are definitely "owned" by the Linux user account for me, not root. Anyway I'll be doing some experiments along the lines of your suggesetions.