# Performing a chmod 400 operation on a .pem file not working no matter what I try

Tags: ssh, permissions

I'm trying to format a .pem file for access to an EC2 instance through SSH, but no matter what I try among suggestions I've seen, nothing seems to work. For context, I have the .pem file stored on my Windows C:// drive.

From just downloading it, I get the following permissions as seen in my WSL shell (and output of ssh command, fails, obviously):
[image]

The following are my attempts to modify this file

1. Used Ubuntu's WSL to chmod the file into 400 (what I assume is `-r--------`): (forgot to unhide my username, lol)
   [image]

1.a.  I have modified my wsl.conf with the following to make sure to allow permissions changes to propagate from my WSL shell ([Unable to change file permissions on Ubuntu Bash for Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1323645/unable-to-change-file-permissions-on-ubuntu-bash-for-windows-10)):

[image]

2. Used Powershell to try to place restrictions on the file (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39404087/pem-file-permissions-on-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows):
   [image]

Now, permissions are `-r--r--r--', which still isn't good enough.

[image]

3. Made sure the file is only readable by user in Windows settings ([Windows SSH: Permissions for 'private-key' are too open](https://superuser.com/questions/1296024/windows-ssh-permissions-for-private-key-are-too-open/1296046)):

[image]

What else can I do here? This is literally all the answers I've found online and they don't work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks y'all!

EDIT: After some reading, it seems that Powershell has some extra ways to reset permissions but I can't seem to find any definitive source.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to change file permissions on Ubuntu Bash for Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1323645/unable-to-change-file-permissions-on-ubuntu-bash-for-windows-10)

Comment: As I mentioned before, I've already tried changing the wsl.conf and it didn't work. Thanks tho!

Comment: Not exactly how amazon describes importing a key ... Have you tied the methods laid out in their own documentation on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#how-to-generate-your-own-key-and-import-it-to-aws ?

Comment: I'm not importing a key, simply using one I downloaded and created when I initialized the instance. The problem I'm trying to solve here is how to change permissions so it can be usable when ssh'ing into my instance.

Comment: Unfortuntaly i dont know why WSL doesnt allow chmod 400. I did find someone's solution was to copy the cert to their WSL home directory (~) and chmod 400 there without problems. (link to discussion https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/81)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WSL will start in your C:\Users{user} directory.

Put the file in /home/{user}, then change the permissions.

Comment: thank you for the help! yes, @Silbee gave the answer to do this as well, and I ended up following it. I appreciate the help though!