# Imported wsl instance has folders with wrong owner/group and cannot be modified

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

I imported a WSL instance to keep my development environment close to that of my co-workers.

Unfortunately, the owner and group of folders like `/mnt/c` are of the person who created that wsl instance. this means I cannot even `cd` into it.

`sudo chown`, `sudo chgrp` and even `sudo chmod` all fail on this folder with 'permission denied'.

```
tyler.shellberg@04-GT81BM2:/mnt$ ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  6 root         root         4096 Jan 25 08:44 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 root         root         4096 Jan 26 08:30 ..
drwxrwx---  1 not.me       not.me       4096 Jan 25 13:38 c
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to change file permissions on Ubuntu Bash for Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1323645/unable-to-change-file-permissions-on-ubuntu-bash-for-windows-10). Windows files have no Linux permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to edit `/etc/wsl.conf` so that the uid and gid matched my id, which I got with `id`. Then I had to shut down wsl with `wsl --shutdown` from a windows terminal and restart it.