# Permissions 0555 for 'Seq.pem' are too open

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I could a repetitive question, but I tried all the solutions I found on the internet and youtube, but I cannot solve it. I'm basically a baby for linux.

I have singed for Nimbus (cloud) to store my data and perform genomic analysis. I had generated.pem key and IP address. I am using Window Subsystem for linux and stored my .pem in a folder in desktop in my local machine for testing purpose. I also tried to removed all users from the .pem key file and keep only myself there using the solution found online, but still did not work. Does anyone could suggest a simple tip to fix it. Do appreciate for your help. Attached is the image from wSL [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAg2I.jpg)

kind Regards,

Synat

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu on Windows 10 - SSH “Permissions xxxx for private key are too open](https://superuser.com/questions/1321072/ubuntu-on-windows-10-ssh-permissions-xxxx-for-private-key-are-too-open)

Comment: I have now fixed it. thank for your response.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the image below:

[image: octal representation]
(from: https://towardsdatascience.com/unix-permissions-the-easy-way-98cc19979b3e)

What you just did, is set read and execute privileges for yourself, your group and everyone else on the system.

This is indeed something that SSH barks at, because it only allows any privilege for the current user.

Use:

```
chmod 600 /path/to/file.pem
```

This will set read+write for you, and no privileges for any other user of the system.

Comment: thanks for your response, mtak. I have moved my .pem file to home directory of WSL using instruction from the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58483727/amazon-ec2-error-warning-unprotected-private-key-file-even-after-changing-t and it worked. I appreciate your response. regards, synat